# Funciones declaradas vs Funciones expresadas

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Tengo una duda con respecto a esto:

Según lo que he leído las funciones declaradas están disponibles para su llamada independientemente de cual sea su posición en el código.

Incluso si la declaración se encuentra al final de todo un código fuente, ésta tendrá preferencia sobre aquellas expresiones que la precedan.

Sin embargo, si tratamos con funciones expresadas, éstas solo son evaluadas cuando el flujo natural de ejecución las alcanza.

En ECMASCRIPT6 esto sigue siendo literalmente así? Porque en el siguiente ejemplo, la web donde he encontrado la información describe:

> Como la función es creada antes que se evalúe el código, en algunos
>   navegadores podemos encontrarnos con que nos saltamos los
>   condicionales y se asigna a la función foo siempre el valor FALSE, que
>   correspondería con la última llamada que se hace.

```
myVar=true;

if( myVar == true){
  function foo(){ return 'TRUE'; }
}else{
  function foo(){ return 'FALSE'; }
}

console.log(foo());
```

Cuando yo pruebo lo anterior, al contrario de lo que se dice, el resultado es TRUE.

¿Realmente se tiene tan encuentra si crear una función de una forma u otra, o por lo contrario se opta mayormente por la declaración (como en casi todos los proyectos me encuentro)?

Answer (score 3):

## Sobre el preámbulo de la pregunta

Una función expresada podría tener la siguiente forma

```
//Ejemplo de función expresada
var miFuncion = function(){
   //Aquí van los enunciados de lo que hará la función expresada
}
```

Otro ejemplo de función expresada es

```
//Ejemplos de función autoejecutada o IIFE por las siglas de su nombre en inglés
(function miOtraFuncion(){})()
```

El ejemplo incluido en la pregunta no contiene funciones expresadas. Las funciones incluidas en la pregunta son funciones "declaradas".

Una función es "declarada" cuando el enunciado empieza con la palabra clave `function`

Una función es "expresada" cuando una expresión es una función. Una expresión es una unidad que devuelve un valor.

## Sobre la pregunta al final del cuerpo de la pregunta

> ¿Realmente se tiene tan encuentra (sic) si crear una función de una forma u otra, o por lo contrario se opta mayormente por la declaración (como en casi todos los proyectos me encuentro)?

Definitivamente se tiene que tomar en cuenta la forma de crear funciones pero en primer lugar esto lo dicta lo que se quiere que haga el programa luego vendrán en consideración objetivos de facilidad de mantenimiento, "buenas prácticas", guías de estilo y preferencias del programador.

Referencia

- [Expresiones y operadores](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)

Comment: Me dejé por poner el código de ejemplo en la primera parte. Igualmente, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Todo dependerá si:

- está activado el modo estricto
- el interprete es ES6

Para implementaciones `ES<6` las funciones no pueden ser declaradas adentro de bloques de estructuras de control, esto es un comportamiento indefenido si está activado el modo stricto, esto lanzará una excepción, de lo contrario el resultado variará según la implementación

la mayoría de navegadores al encontrarse esta problemática realizan el isado

```
if (true) {
  function foo () { return true };
} else {
  function foo () { return false }; 
}
console.log(foo()); // false
```

es equivalente a

```
function foo () { return true };
function foo () { return false };

if (true) {
  ; //no-op
} else {
  ; //no-op
}
console.log(foo()); // false
```

En modo stricto esto lanzará una excepción

[image: Internet Explorer 10 modo esctricto]

---

Para implementaciones `ES>=6` las definiciones de funciones heredarán el ámbito del bloque, y se evaluarán las expresiones permitiendo que puedas cambiar la definición de la función e incluso no exportarla (contrario al isado)

así:

```
if (true) {
  function foo () { return true };
} else {
  function foo () { return false };
}
console.log(foo());
```

es aproximadamente igual

```
{
  var foo;
  if (true) {
    foo = function foo () { return true };
  } else {
    foo = function foo () { return false };
  }
  if (foo !== undefined) window.foo = foo // window porque es el scope global
}
console.log(foo());
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069204/function-declarations-inside-if-else-statements#answer-10069457